# Angular2-Meteor *ngIf with Meteor.userId() not updating reactively

Tags: angular, meteor, angular2-meteor

I am still pretty new to angular2-meteor and am trying a simple custom login buttons component.  I want to display Sign Up and Log In buttons when there is no user logged in and display the Log Out button when a user is logged in.  It seemed like it ought to be pretty simple, but it doesn't work as I am expecting.

Here is my component html:

```
<div *ngIf="!isLoggedIn()">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" (click)="goToLoginForm()">Log In</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Sign Up</button>
</div>

<div *ngIf="isLoggedIn()">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" (click)="logout()">Log Out</button>
</div>
```

And here is my typescript:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import template from "./login-buttons.component.html";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: "login-buttons",
    template
})
export class LoginButtonsComponent {

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    isLoggedIn(): boolean {
        return !!Meteor.user();
    }

    goToLoginForm(): void {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    }

    logout(): void {
        Meteor.logout((error) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                this.router.navigateByUrl("/");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm sure I am missing something really simple, but it eludes me.  All help is appreciated.

Comment: let me know if this solution works for you or not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there can be so many answer to your question. you can use user injection which is very simple. 
first you should use Meteor.userId();

```
 isLoggedIn(): boolean {
            return !!Meteor.userId();
        }
```

this one below is standard answer

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import template from "./login-buttons.component.html";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import { InjectUser } from 'angular2-meteor-accounts-ui';//<--**** import this****

@Component({
    selector: "login-buttons",
    template
})
@InjectUser('user') //<--*** add this***
export class LoginButtonsComponent {
    user: Meteor.User; //<--*** add this ***
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    isLoggedIn(): boolean {
        return !!Meteor.user();
    }

    goToLoginForm(): void {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    }

    logout(): void {
        Meteor.logout((error) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                this.router.navigateByUrl("/");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and your html should be like this

```
<div *ngIf="!user">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" (click)="goToLoginForm()">Log In</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Sign Up</button>
</div>

<div *ngIf="user">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" (click)="logout()">Log Out</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Amit.  I switched to Meteor.userId() and the behavior is the same.  Interestingly, I noticed that if I click in the page after login/logout that then I see the change, but it doesn't happen automatically.  Tried in both Chrome and Safari.  I knew about the @InjectUser trick, but I didn't want to import that whole package just for that.

Comment: let me give you few tips. this will help you. @user3101499 you should never use a function inside  *ngIf. because *ngIf automatically rerun to detect changes in what is inside "" so your function will keep on runing every second to detect changes. this will reduce your app performance. so use second method. it will work and you will need that package so much if you want to work in meteor.js

Comment: Meteor.userId function don't work properly in html rendering part. i think that why its creating problem in your case. if you face any other issue in angular 2 meteor you can directly contact me :)

Comment: Thanks, Amit.  That did the trick.  I'll look forward to your help on the next issue.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The helper `isLoggedIn` can be treated as a property, calling it from the UI doesn't make sense. In other words, just remove the brackets from the ngIf. You can modify your html to look like this

```
<div *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" (click)="logout()">Log Out</button>
</div>
```